# lander of game, not landing on the landing pad but passing through

Tags: c#, xna

i want to get the lander of this xna game to successfully touchdown on the landing pad, and then play the sound, however, it passes right through and the sound still plays. the complete code for this is:

```
namespace MoonLander
{
  /// <summary>
  /// This is the main type for your game
  /// </summary>
  public class BasicLunarLander : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
  {         
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    SoundEffectInstance EndGameSoundInstance;
    Texture2D BackgroundImage;
    Texture2D LandingImage;
    SoundEffect EndGameSound;
    int LanderPosX;
    int LanderPosY;
    Texture2D LandingPadImage;



    public BasicLunarLander()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        LanderPosX = 100;
        LanderPosY = 0;

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);



        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        BackgroundImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("background");
        LandingImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("lander");
        LandingPadImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("landingpad");
        EndGameSound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("crowdcheer");
        EndGameSoundInstance = EndGameSound.CreateInstance();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();


        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            LanderPosY = LanderPosY + 2;
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            LanderPosY = LanderPosY - 2;
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            LanderPosX = LanderPosX - 2;
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            LanderPosX = LanderPosX + 2;
        }

        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        Rectangle rectLander = new Rectangle(LanderPosX, LanderPosY, LandingImage.Width, LandingImage.Height);
        Rectangle rectLandingPad = new Rectangle(350, 500, LandingPadImage.Width, LandingPadImage.Height);

        if (rectLander.Intersects(rectLandingPad))
        {
            EndGameSoundInstance.Play();

        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {



        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
          spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(BackgroundImage, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(LandingImage, new Vector2(LanderPosX, LanderPosY), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(LandingPadImage, new Vector2(350,500), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope you can help me with this issue, thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're not doing anything about preventing movement after the lander has landed (the condition has been met). The sound plays of course, because that is what you did code.

Add a variable detecting if it has landed and declare it inside your class

```
bool _hasLanded = false;
```

then wrap the key detection in your update method (for up, down, left and right keys) inside and if:

```
if(!_hasLanded)
{
//keypresses go here
}
```

and finally, inside your `if` where you check to see if the rectangles intersect, add

```
_hasLanded = true;
```

That should prevent you from being able to move the lander once it has touched the landing pad.